# Bundling hyperhtml-element with browserify/babelify not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs, hyperhtml

Maybe I'm doing something very wrong but I can't seem to get hyperhtml-element to play nice with babel.

If I import HyperHTMLElement from 'hyperhtml-element' then I get raw es6 in my bundle.
If I import HyperHTMLElement from 'hyperhtml-element/es5' then I get Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

I'm using @babel/preset-env

I've been using hyperhtml-element in an Electron app for the last couple month and love it. But now that I'm trying to use it on the web I can't even figure out how to bundle it. I've been trying to make this work for almost a month now.

This is my `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp')

var browserify = require('browserify')
var watchify = require('watchify')
var babelify = require('babelify')

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer')
var merge = require('utils-merge')

var rename = require('gulp-rename')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')


/* nicer browserify errors */
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var chalk = require('chalk')

function map_error(err) {
  if (err.fileName) {
    // regular error
    gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
      + ': '
      + chalk.yellow(err.fileName.replace(__dirname + '/src/js/', ''))
      + ': '
      + 'Line '
      + chalk.magenta(err.lineNumber)
      + ' & '
      + 'Column '
      + chalk.magenta(err.columnNumber || err.column)
      + ': '
      + chalk.blue(err.description))
  } else {
    // browserify error..
    gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
      + ': '
      + chalk.yellow(err.message))
  }

  this.emit('end');
}

gulp.task('watchify', function () {
  var args = merge(watchify.args, { debug: true })
  var bundler = watchify(browserify('./src/js/index.js', args)).transform(babelify, { /* opts */ })
  bundle_js(bundler)

  bundler.on('update', function () {
    bundle_js(bundler)
  })
})

function bundle_js(bundler) {
  return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', map_error)
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/static/js'))
    .pipe(rename('index.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      // capture sourcemaps from transforms
      .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/static/js/'))
}

// Without watchify
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  var bundler = browserify('./src/js/index.js', { debug: true }).transform(babelify, {/* options */ })

  return bundle_js(bundler)
})

// Without sourcemaps
gulp.task('browserify-production', function () {
  var bundler = browserify('./src/js/index.js').transform(babelify, {presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]})

  return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', map_error)
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(rename('index.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/static/js/'))
})
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I `import HyperHTMLElement from 'hyperhtml-element'` then I get raw es6 in my bundle.

Which is exactly what should happen, right ? You are using ES6 syntax, you get it.

But here you are bundling with browserify, which AFAIK doesn't even understand ES6, only CommonJS.

Accordingly, if you want to `require` HyperHTMLElement for CommonJS you have to be a bit more specific:

```
// explicit 
const HyperHTMLElement = require('hyperhtml-element/cjs').default;
```

If your bundler is smart enough to understand `.default` automatically and you have some conversion behind the scene from ES6 to ES5/CJS, then you might try the following instead, still pointing at the right folder:

```
// implicit CJS
import HyperHTMLElement from 'hyperhtml-element/cjs';
```

One of the two will surely works, if the target env is CJS.

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of. The target is the browser and the problem is that ES6 code (`const`, `let`, etc.) still remains in the final bundle. As far as I can tell it is because bablify is not compling anything from `./node_modules/`. Which, as I understand it, is the intended behavior; though it doesn't help me much.

Comment: I have been spending to much time trying to resolve this so I decided to ditch browserify altogether and I'm currently setting up `typescript > temp folder > rollup > babel` as my build process. Propably not ideal but it will get the job done

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: I use it daily in production with browserify and everything is fine, but admittedly I am not transforming all the things. I think if you use Babel 7 though, you should be fine with just regular import, and Babel will figure out what to do. Watch out with TypeScript classes transform because these are broken since about ever. More about these well known issues in here https://itnext.io/js-is-not-worse-than-84a5fca0e87d

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about TS; I never knew that. Also, excellent article. Thanks again